# MYSQL inner join Error - Unknown column 'm.account_no' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I don't know what to call it, I am trying to explain it.

I have two table :

**1. Member**

[image]

**2. share_trx_history**

[image]

One member can have multiple share records, I have to display it in following structure
(Total debit, credit, balance opening of the given year)

```
+-----------+------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
|account_no | name | debit | credit | balance | opening|
+-----------+------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
```

I have tried this but it failed:

```
SELECT m.account_no, m.name, share.*
FROM `member` AS m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sth.account_no AS sth_account_no, SUM(sth.debit) AS sth_debit, SUM(sth.credit) AS sth_credit,(
    SELECT sth2.balance 
    FROM `share_trx_history` AS sth2 
    WHERE sth2.account_no=m.account_no
    ORDER BY sth2.share_issue_date ASC 
    LIMIT 0,1
) AS sth_balance, 
    (SELECT balance
        FROM `share_trx_history` AS sth3
        WHERE year(sth3.share_issue_date ) <2014 AND sth3.account_no=m.account_no
        ORDER BY sth3.share_issue_date DESC
        LIMIT 0 , 1) AS sth_opening 
FROM `share_trx_history` AS sth 
WHERE sth.share_issue_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 Year)
AND sth.account_no=m.account_no) AS share
ON share.sth_account_no =  m.account_no
```

Giving following error:

```
Unknown column 'm.account_no' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any simple way to accomplish it?

What's wrong with my query?

Thank you

**Update:**

`balance = (total debit + total dividend) - (total credit)`

Please check `opening = previous year balance`

Comment: Can you share your table structures in `http://sqlfiddle.com/`?

Comment: ok I am sharing it on sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.account_no, m.name, SUM(sth.debit) AS sth_debit, SUM(sth.credit) AS sth_credit, 
       MAX(CASE share_issue_date WHEN start_date THEN balance ELSE 0 END) AS sth_balance, 
       MAX(CASE share_issue_date WHEN opening_date THEN balance ELSE 0 END) AS sth_opening
FROM `member` AS m 
INNER JOIN share_trx_history AS sth ON m.account_no = sth.account_no
INNER JOIN (SELECT account_no, MIN(share_issue_date) start_date, MAX(share_issue_date) opening_date
            FROM share_trx_history WHERE YEAR(share_issue_date) <2014 GROUP BY account_no
          ) AS A ON sth.account_no = A.account_no AND share_issue_date IN (start_date, opening_date)
WHERE sth.share_issue_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY m.account_no
```

Comment: Thank you @Saharsh Shah for help but,  `balance = (debit+devidend) -(credit)`, Please check `opening = previous year balance `, Your Answer is very much helpful

Comment: @Saharsha wait sir its some kind of interest, Just treat as a Column to add to debit